# What is a Professional way to customize personal note in linkedin

Tags: interviewing, linkedin, australia

Background : Mr.John is emigrating (from USA) to Australia in mid of 2014 and would like to get in the circle with recruiters so he can be in touch with Australian IT market.

What is the most professional way to customize a personal note in linkedin (that comes up as an option when you are connecting to someone on linkedin and generically says : I'd like to add you to my professional network on LinkedIn.). A template would be great.

Edit: This is the current note "Hello, 
I am in the process of applying for an Australian PR and I would be interested to keep in touch with you for job openings in the future." How could this be improved ? Any other templates are more than welcome please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely recommend customizing Linked In messages.  At least in my experience, this is done all too rarely, making it fairly difficult to figure out why one has been connected to.

In my experience, recruiters are pretty eager to build a wide network, so I don't see any problem with your initial approach, the main point is:

- why did you want to connect?
- what are you looking to get out of the connection?'

Which you've covered.  After that, keep it short and sweet (as you've done) - Linked In is built for very short messages, so writing anything longer than 2-3 sentences is not expected or required.

To take it one step further though...

**Personalize**

Do some digging on the recruiter - know what kind of jobs they are touch with and why it's good to connect to this specific person.  I, personally, don't find that the majority of my recruiter connections have been useful, so I'd recommend being fairly sure that the connection is worth while.

In communication, highlight the areas of work of this particular recruiter - either in the request or after the connectio - that you are particularly interested in... for example:

- I see you've done work with Company X.  I'm particularly interested in companies like this which are (insert attributes)...
- I see you're connected to people A, B, C - they are colleagues of mine, and I have a great deal of personal respect for them.  I have a similar skill set and am looking for...

I'd be inclined to do this after the initial link, to keep the communication small and streamlined.

**Touch base**

The world of the recruiter seems to change weekly - so don't assume that because you connected a month ago and didn't hear anything more means that there's nothing to talk about.  Keep a dialogue going and find a way to touch base weekly.  Being linked on Linked In doesn't replace the need to check in and keep in contact.